# Star Rating In Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, rating-system

I have build an application in asp.net for which I require a star rating concept. I have never dealt with that earlier, I have done a lot of googling but I cant find the perfect and best one.

I have gone through [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/06/7-jquery-star-rating-plugin-examples.html) link but I cant make it.

Comment: What have you try till now?

Comment: This functionality is included in the AjaxControlToolkit library, more info [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Rating/Rating.aspx).

Comment: Yes i can use the ajaxcontrol toolkit.But how what can be the code for this to store the contact information who had rated for this... Is there references for this, from where i can follow the stapes..

Answer (score 1):

Ajax Control Toolkit's Star Rating Control Provides this functionality. More Info on http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Rating/Rating.aspx